# change RecyclerView item to be above all others

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have horizontal recyclerView that contains images as items.
How can I detect when a RecycleView item is in the center of the screen and emphasize it to be something like this :

**Example :**

[image: example]

Comment: You can check CorouselLayout for recyclerview. check this:https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager

Comment: Try using [Carousel Layout with ViewPager](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html) also some libraries are there [library](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager)

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot and I learned new and useful library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the carousel logic with RecyclerView combination and SnapHelper compatibility class like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal" />
```

Then attach your recyclerView with SnapHelper class:

```
LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

And provide the logic for currently selected centered item:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            float pos = (float) recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset() / (float) itemHeight;
            int itemPos = (int) Math.floor(pos);
        }
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
});
```