# How to show exactly 5 items in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm looking to achieve something like this:

[image]

Where the RecyclerView shows a list of **endless repeating (Circular) items**, but only **shows 5 items** at any given time. The endless scrolling part is done, but the sizing can't seem to work right.
There is also the fact that the center item has to be larger, so I can't grab the width of the screen and make the item 1/5 of the screen.

Is it possible to achieve this on all screens?

Comment: you can make a custom layout of five elements or you can use gridLayout manager in recycler view with column count five and make middle element view like this

Comment: if you want to make 1 item above all others check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760805/change-recyclerview-item-to-be-above-all-others)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like :

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return  5;
}
```

it works for me in the adapter class you can change items as you want to display

Comment: Please read the question carefully, the RecyclerView is **Endless**

Comment: it works try this

Comment: By showing only 5 items, that means there is no scrolling. Only 5 items that are changed when the selection is change. Which isn't what I want.

Comment: I did not get what do you want to do? share code